# How to execute a C# code in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

This is a simple question, but it is a bit hard for Unity newbie like me.

I have coded this. (See below.)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite; 
using System.Data; 
using System;

public class NewBehaviourScript1 : MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    string conn = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/sensor.sqlite"; //Path to database.
    IDbConnection dbconn;
    dbconn = (IDbConnection) new SqliteConnection(conn);
    dbconn.Open(); //Open connection to the database.
    IDbCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();

    string sqlQuery = "SELECT x1 " + "FROM sport";
    dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
    IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int value = reader.GetInt32(0);
        string name = reader.GetString(1);
        int rand = reader.GetInt32(2);
    }

    reader.Close();
    reader = null;
    dbcmd.Dispose();
    dbcmd = null;
    dbconn.Close();
    dbconn = null;

}
```

}

and saved.

However, I do not know how to execute this. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: See this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn759441.aspx and this http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html.
I also recomend you watch this http://www.lynda.com/Unity-3D-tutorials/Advanced-Unity-3D-Game-Programming/160270-2.html.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to associate the script to an object (you can use "Empty Object") and then you run the project.

As posted in the comments, this is probably your best starting point. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html

As a quick primer:

`Start()` is ran once upon loading (or "creating" the object -- done automatically if you add the object via the GUI). `Update()` is ran on every frame render and is done as fast as possible. So the higher the frame rate the more executions.

Answer (score 1):

in unity, create a new empty object. in this empty object add component, select new c# script. add this objet to your scene.

double click the new c sharp script, it will open the IDE and you will have a template script (should have Start() and Update())

this is where your code goes

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new game object in the unity3d. Select the game object, then in the Inspectotr, Add Component->Scripts, select the C# code that you write.